# Mongoose query penultimate item from array of objects

Tags: arrays, database, mongoose, aggregation-framework, match

I have schemas each containing an array of objects looking like this:

```
{name: String, _id: ObjectId}
```

Each schemas array has multiple items, I need to match the penultimate (next to last) items _id inside an aggregate function, which currently looks like this:

```
{ "$match": {$expr: {$gt: [{"$arrayElemAt": ["$path._id", -2]}, mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)]}}},
{ "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": 1,
        "isFile": {
            "$cond": [{"$eq": [{"$ifNull":["$data", null]}, null]},false, true]
        }
    }
}
```

(the current match function is my attempt, however it does not work)
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answer: use $eq instead of $gt...